# Update value in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to update a value in a table from another table where it is stored as per the source table mentioned below. When I try to update this into my target table, it is only picking up the value before the space and not the whole value.

Source table

```
122 3456
451 2341
C73759  9058
```

Target table (currently)

```
122
451
C73759
```

Can you please tell me how to correct this?

Query I'm using,

```
INSERT INTO  abc
(
    custidID,                       --MemberID
    salespersonID,                      --ProviderID
    StartDate,                      --Start Date
    FinishDate                      --End Date
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    cust number,
    sales person id , 
    start date,
    '010120009'
FROM
    source tablename
order by 1,2
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the query you are using and an explanation on what the result of that query is and what the _desired_ result is. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: are the values in source table displayed here are stored in 2 columns?

Comment: no karthik, its the same column. Its just that the values are stored in a space separated manner for some reason. I need to pick this same value but without the spaces in between in my destination table.